# JavaScript to PHP thorugh AJAX - PHP gets empty array

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm trying to to send a file to PHP from JavaScript through AJAX, but PHP receives an empty array.

I'm currently trying to create a web page through which I can pass file to PHP, so it can access and save information from within to DB. Even though JavaScript has the file and via inspect tools I confirmed that the file is in fact send, the array which PHP receives is empty.

File gets to JavaScript from HTML through input type file. Due to testing I'm sure that part works well.

```
function post($event)
    {
      var script = document.createElement('script');
      script.scr = '//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js';
      document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);




      try
      {
        var fileSTA = $event[0];

         var formData = new FormData();
         formData.append('file', fileSTA);

         $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                processData: false, // required
                contentType: false, // required
                url: 'saveSTAtoDatabase.php',// do roota wrzucic pliki
                data: formData,
               //  data: {'file': formData},    //formData vs fileSTA  // just checking

                success: function(data)
                          { 
                              alert(data);
                          },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) 
                {
                 alert("Ajax error: " + xhr.status + " (" + thrownError + ")");
                }
                });
        }
        catch(err)
        {
          alert("JavaScript error: " + err);
        }
    }
```

I'll include php to give an idea of how Iam trying to access the data send.
Edit: I think I created some confusion with line above, my end goal is to access the data inside the file. Below code is to show what return messages I get.

```php
<?php
    $file = $_POST;
    var_dump($file); //returns: array(0) {}
    var_dump($_POST); //returns: array(0) {}
    echo $_GET['file']; //returns: Undefined index: file
    echo $_POST['file'];  //returns: Undefined index: file

?>
```

I expect the file to be passed to PHP so it can access the data inside the file and process it further.

Sorry if this question was asked before, but all the threads I found were not applicable to me. I'm a new dev please don't hate on me too much.

```
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <input id="hejka" type="file" onchange="post(this.files)"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{sugar_getjspath file='include/javascript/popup_parent_helper.js'}"></script>
```

Comment: You're passing `filee`, but looking for `file`... `formData.append('filee', fileSTA);`

Comment: My mistake, it’s a leftover from some testing I did to figure out the problem.

Comment: try to check $_FILES instead of $_POST and set contentType to false in your request

Comment: How does your HTML look like? Did you add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to the form?

Comment: What is the content of `$event[0]`? Also, I think the `data` field must be an already serialized FormData, not the object.

Comment: @Refilon added html part for clarification

Comment: @solarc $event[0] is the file, the HTML sends an array with one element.  I’ve read somewhere that post should take care of serializing. I tried it like this $(fileSTA).serialize(); and it returned an empty array.

Comment: @MohammedElBanyaoui I did what you suggested an in return got an array with File’s name, type, tmp_name, error and size. All had data except for error which was empty.

Comment: @solarc — Passing a FormData object is fine.

Comment: **Danger** — jquery-1.12.0 — jQuery 1.x is unsupported and doesn't get security updates. Use a supported version of jQuery.

Comment: it's all what you need, use move_uploaded_file() -to Moves an uploaded file to a new location

Comment: @MohammedElBanyaoui — They can't move the file until they can read its tempory path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems:

---

## Broken Content Type

(NB: Since writing this answer, the question was edited to remove this problem)

> ```
> contentType: '', // required
> ```

This sets the content-type to an empty string. PHP can't parse the POST body without knowing what the content-type is.

Change it to:

```
contentType: false,
```

This tells jQuery to not set the Content-Type *at all*, which lets the underlying XMLHttpRequest object infer it from the FormData object.

---

## Looking in the wrong places

Submitted files do not appear in `$_POST` or `$_GET`. They appear in `$_FILES`.

Change the PHP:

```
var_dump($_FILES);
```

---

After making these changes, the code worked when I tested it locally.

Comment: Okay I did it, and got file information: name, type, tmp_name, error and size. With error being the only one empty. But how do I now access the data inside the file. I thought $_FILES only gives basic information about files sent. I realise my end goal might have not been stated in the question.

Comment: You've got the tmp_name, so use that to open the file. e.g. with https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Comment: That's it! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

your code must be like this please do your problem will solve this code

```
print_r($_FILES)// return file array

print_r($_FILES['file']); // return an array named file

echo $_FILES['file']['name']; // returns filename
```